# How do I do a 'git blame' in NetBeans?

Tags: git, netbeans

NetBeans has built-in support for git. Can I do a `git blame` inside NetBeans? If so, how?

I [googled](https://www.google.nl/search?q=netbeans+git+blame) it, but that didn't turn up anything useful. Also the [NetBeans git tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html) does not mention `git blame`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

- Main menu "`Team->Show Annotations`" OR
- "`Git->Show Annotations`" in the context menu of a file in the project/files view OR
- define a shortcut for the action "`Show Annotations`" (Category Git) in the keymap options

Comment: FWIW, works for subversion as well (substitute Subversion to Git in the answer).