# Is there any way to adjust Netbeans to show history line by line aside programming area?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, revision-history

I am using Git. For looking into history we need to click history tab and another window opens show dif to previous and current.

Like Intellij, where history of Line is shown in left gadget, which show date and author who checked in code. Is there any way or plugin to get similar screens in netbeans?

Comment: linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348352/how-do-i-do-a-git-blame-in-netbeans

Comment: (since you mentioned IntelliJ, I found the same feature there is **VCS** > **Git** > **Annotate** or if you have the Version Control tool window or a diff view open, **Right Click** > **Annotate**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on the editor's tab, then ghoose "Git -> Show Annotations"

The last commit and the committer are shown in the left area of the editor then. If you hover the mouse over that is also shows you the commit message:

[image]